# catastrophic backtracking error validation string

Tags: javascript

^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$

I have used above regex to perform validation on input string for below scenarios.

- I want to allow only hyphen ('-'), period ('.') & underscore ('_')
- name should not start or end with hyphen ('-'), period ('.') & underscore ('_')
- name should not contain Spaces
- Two consecutive special characters (from set of (._-)) are not allowed

And I have validated it through javascript.

But, when we add name having special characters at the end, browser halts/ hangs  instead of returning false.

```
var regex = new RegExp("^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-]?)+[a-zA-Z0-9]+$");
        if (regex.test($('#txtBox1').val())) {//success}
```

Comment: I want to allow only hyphen ('-'), period ('.') & underscore ('_')

Comment: sdggq6585555555555com5jmdsfgsdgdsgsgdsgsdggggggggggdsgcom.

Answer (score 1):

Don't make those special delimiters optional in your repeated group:

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+[._-])*[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
#                 ^ ^
```

That still matches the same, but it can't backtrack to apply the optional character in positions where it doesn't appear.

Comment: @gurvinder372 There must always be `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` between them

Comment: Got it `[._-]` is part of first capturing group itself.

Comment: Thank you... It worked for me. In addition to this can we add length constraint(min, max) for entire string

Answer (score 0):

Try this as well

```
var isValid = !!str.match(/[^\w.-]/i) 
           && !str.split(/[._-]/).filter( s => s.length == 0 ).length;
```

**Explanation**

- `str.match(/[^\w.-]/i)`  checks if there is any character matching which is neither *alphanumeric*, *underscore*, *dot* nor *hypen*.
- `str.split(/[._-]/)` splits the input by these three characters `[._-]` and then check if there is any *empty string*. If these characters are at the *beginning* or *end* or *consecutively placed*, then there will be an *empty string* in the resultant array.